# how to destroy Owl-carousel class that have multiple div

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

how to destroy Owl-carousel  class that have multiple div.I have to destroy when change into mobile mode and again init when desktop mode change?? please somebody help me..

```
function resizeWindow() {

  if ($(window).width() <= 600) {

    $("#options-list").owlCarousel({
      loop: true, //options-list-owl-               
      items: 3,


      pagination: false,
    });
    if (typeof $(".product-list").data('owlCarousel') !== 'undefined') {

      $(".product-list").data('owlCarousel').destroy();
    }
  } else {

    $(".product-list").owlCarousel({
      loop: true, //product-list-owl-
      items: 3,
      itemsDesktop: [1024, 3],
      pagination: false,
    });
    if (typeof $("#options-list").data('owlCarousel') !== 'undefined')
      $("#options-list").data('owlCarousel').destroy();


  }
}
```

Comment: I think your method of destroying owlCarousel is incorrect. Try `$("#product-list").owlCarousel('destroy');`

Comment: but i need to remove class of multiple div

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: i am having multiple div to init same owl-carousel..so i am using class here what the procedure to destroy all owl-carousel class